# Center a div on the screen in every browser

Tags: css, html, margin, center

I have a div that contain my form (as a blue box). I need center that div in the screen for every browser. I searched about this and people said that if I put margin as `auto` it should work.

But no, this put my box (the div) at the left side in every browser.

```
<HTML>
..
...
<body>

<div id="questionare">

<form .....
....
....
</form>
         </div>

</body>

...
....

</HTML>
```

**and on my CSS I tried things like:**

```
#questionare{

 margin: 0 auto ;
 position:relative;
 width: 300px; 
 text-align: left;
 background:rgb(127, 177, 198);
 padding: 88px 79px 29px; 
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0px 5px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
-webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
-moz-border-radius: 10px; -khtml-border-radius: 10px; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4); 
-moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4); 
-khtml-box-shadow: 0 5px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
 behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
}
```

**-or-**

```
#questionare{
 margin-left: auto ;
 margin-right: auto ;
 position:relative;
width: 300px;

text-align: left;
background:rgb(127, 177, 198);
padding: 88px 79px 29px; 
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 0px 5px 12px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
-webkit-border-radius: 10px; 
-moz-border-radius: 10px; -khtml-border-radius: 10px; 
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4); 
-moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4); 
-khtml-box-shadow: 0 5px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);

behavior: url(/PIE.htc);


}
```

**Form style is empty**

```
form{

}
```

What is the solution?

Comment: You're formatting is incorrect. See my answer for an example and see it working with the correct formatting using the html and css you have given.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a DTD like

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Answer (score 1):

It actually works for me, see the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L7gt2/).

I haven't changed anything of your code.

Your issue could be that you're missing a `doctype`, forcing the browser to render in quirks mode.

Comment: WOW !That so extrange , now im using this doctipe that a user recomend me here:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  . My file is a php too ( but tha shouldnt be the problem)

Answer (score 0):

Besides using the Doctype as sugested on other answers,
You need to have this css rules:

```
body{text-align: center;}
.wrapper{
text-align: left;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100px; /* or your desired size, or no size if you want the div to be 100% */
height: 100px; /* or your desired size, or no size if you want the div to be 100% */
}
```

It's important to set the body text-align to center so it work in all browsers

Comment: Thanks for your help , i just see my bug , i had before that code a Image header with position: absolute; .

Answer (score 0):

At most times its better not to use the centralized div to style its content instead do this.

```
#questionaire{
position:realative;
margin:auto;
width:300px;
}
#questionaire_innner_div{
position:relative;
float:left;
padding: 88px 79px 29px; 
width:242px;
}
```

Then your html should look like so.

```
<div id="questionaire">
<div id="questionaire_innner_div">

<form>
...
...
...
</form>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix the layout of your tags and the layout will work as it should. So `</div>` and not `< /div>` for example.

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/XscZK/

Comment: Thanks for your help , i just see my bug , i had before that code a Image header with position: absolute;

Comment: No problem. With your code in the right format your css and elements will work as they should. You can then center your images in the same way as well.